# Render partial :collection => @array specify variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am rendering a partial like this:

```
$("#box_container").html("<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => 'contacts/contact_tile', :collection => @contacts) %>")
```

Problem is that my partial is expecting the variable 'contact'.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `contact'
```

I simply want to tell the partial to expect a variable `contact`. Should iterate through `@contacts` as `contact`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Found this is also helpful from the docs. You aren't limited to having the variable named after the partial:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

> To use a custom local variable name within the partial, specify the
>   :as option in the call to the partial:

```
<%= render :partial => "product", :collection => @products, :as => :item %>
```

With this change, you can access an instance of the @products collection as the item local variable within the partial."

Comment: this is strangely not working for me in Rails 4.1.  Was it added in 4.2 or something?

Comment: This works, but *only if you specify `partial:`*. You cannot do `render "product", collection: @projects, as: :item`. You need to specify `partial: "product"` or the `as` option isn't applied.

Comment: @coreyward is correct, confirmed by Rails documentation: `If you're not going to be using any of the options like collections or layouts, you can also use the short-hand defaults of render to render partials.` for at least `5.1.3`.

Answer (score 17):

The documentation at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html says:

> When a partial is called with a pluralized collection, then the
>   individual instances of the partial have access to the member of the
>   collection being rendered via a variable named after the partial.

So it will be passed a variable called "contact_tile" instead of "contact". Perhaps you can just rename your partial.

If this naming is important, you could do it explicitly without the collection option by something like:

```
@contacts.each { |contact| render :partial => 'contacts/contact_tile', :locals => {:contact => contact } }
```

(although as a commenter pointed out, this may not be as performant)

Comment: see below answer. it's easy to override this behavior by overriding the name of the variable with the :as option.

Comment: You could simply write `render @contacts`, convention over configuration, you know. `@contacts` is an array of `Contact` instances, so every `contact` record returns `'contacts/contact'` on `to_partial_path` invocation (Rails does this under the hood). http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html#class-ActionView::PartialRenderer-label-Rendering+the+default+case

Comment: Your code example will parse and compile the template `N` times, and may slow down your site.

Comment: @dskecse , I think you could change your comment to a post answer.

Answer (score 16):

Latest syntax are :

index.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: "product", collection: @products %>
```

_product.html.erb

```
<p>Product Name: <%= product.name %></p>
```

`@products` is used in partial as `product`

Where @products can be considered as `Product.all`
and `product` can be considered as a row of product i.e. `Product.first` as looped all product one by one.

Comment: NOTE: You can't use a symbol for the `partial` value, like `:product`. You need to use a String, like you have it `"product"`. I learnt that the hard way and it ended up defaulting to the  model partial of the collection instead of the custom partial I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a custom variable name as the default with the keyword `as:`

```
<%= render partial: 'line_items/line_item', collection: order.line_items, as: :item %>
```