# Render collection using a partial giving "undefined method for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render a collection of `Projects` using a project partial but I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `customer' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):
1: <p><%= company_name(@project) %><p>
```

The stacktrace is:

```
app/helpers/projects_helper.rb:4:in `company_name'
app/views/projects/_summary.html.erb:1:in
app/views/customers/index.html.erb:11:in
```

So, my index checks that their are projects to start with:

```
<% if @projects.any? %>
  <%= render :partial => "projects/summary", :collection => @projects %>
<% end %>
```

My partial (_summary.html.erb) is simply:

```
<p><%= company_name(@project) %><p>
<p><%= summary_description(@project) %><p>
```

and my ProjectsHelper `company_name` method is

```
def company_name(project)
  if project.customer.business_name.blank?
  ...Do stuff...
```

If I do the following via the rails console, it works fine:

```
projects.first.customer.business_name.blank?
```

I'm really confused because I thought that's what rendering a collection was supposed to do. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.

It was because I was using a differently-named partial to the model I was trying to render. I needed to just render a summary of the model, so I used a summary partial. In the partial though, the "name" of my project variable was "summary". So I changed my partial to:

```
<p><%= company_name(summary) %><p>
<p><%= summary_description(summary) %><p>
```

and it worked. Rails is still a mystery to me with stuff like this. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188381/render-partial-collection-array-specify-variable-name) post, the answer is to use: :as => :foo

```
<%= render :partial => "projects/summary", :collection => @projects, :as => :project %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should change your partial to

```
<p><%= company_name(project) %><p>
<p><%= summary_description(project) %><p>
```

See the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) about this under "Rendering Collections".

Comment: I see what you're saying from the docs. I now get `undefined local variable or method 'project'` from the same line though