# How to pass an array into a partial with another name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one model each for Cars, Trucks, Buses, Vans, etc and I list them in their own controller and view:

#### Cars index.html.slim

```
- if @cars.present?
  .pagination.justify-content-center
    = will_paginate @cars
  - else
    = t "search.sorry_no_results"
```

#### Trucks index.html.slim

```
- if @trucks.present?
  .pagination.justify-content-center
    = will_paginate @trucks
  - else
    = t "search.sorry_no_results"
```

And so on with Buses, Vans, etc.

I want to turn that repetitive chunk into a partial. However, I'm unable to pass the @cars @trucks into a @vehicles array so that all those models can share that partial:

#### Cars index

```
= render partial: "pagination", collection: @cars, as: :vehicles
```

#### _pagination.html.slim

```
- if vehicles.present?
  .pagination.justify-content-center
    = will_paginate vehicles
- else
  = t "search.sorry_no_results"
```

---

#### My Solution

Since I **do not** want to itemize the array, my simple solution is just to pass **all** the arrays:

#### _pagination.html.slim

```
.pagination.justify-content-center
  - if @cars.present?
    = will_paginate @cars
  - elsif @trucks.present?
    = will_paginate @trucks
  - elsif @buses.present?
    = will_paginate @buses
  - elsif @vans.present?
    = will_paginate @vans
  - elsif @...
    ...
  - else
    = t "search.sorry_no_results"
```

Comment: Try: render partial: “pagination”, locals: {pagination: @cars} and in if pagination.present?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188381/render-partial-collection-array-specify-variable-name

Comment: Unrelated, but the variable type is irrelevant.